# pass form values from one page to a hidden iframe inside page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe, webforms

I am trying to take on a new project creatively. Basically, I have a website where I want to put a custom form and a hidden iframe which will contain its own form. What I want is that when I press the submit button on the page's form, the values of say the text boxes will be passed to the iframe's form's text boxes and then submit the hidden form and display in a visible iframe the results.
I have looked through other questions, but none seem to have the same goal as I.

Is this possible? If so, how? I would highly appreciate any help.

nvncbl

Comment: Why are you using a hidden iframe for submitting data when you're just going to show the results anyway? It doesn't seem like you need iframes at all for this situation.

Comment: Sean, I don't want the form in the iframe to be visible as it is very unformatted and my page will be a lot more stylistic. I only want to show the results which match the flow of my page a lot better. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't have a hidden form on your actual page instead of a hidden iframe containing a form?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to pass some input parameters without the page reload. If so, then you should dig into **ajax** in order to call asynchronously different parts of the web page.

Fortunatelly there are many frameworks that can help you. I prefer [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), but you can use for instance [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org/) or [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) and so on.

Comment: Thank you Ricardo, I will look into all these. Have you personally done something like this with one of these solutions?

Comment: No, I have not - there was no need, but quick research showed, that tutorials in Angular.js documentation contain almost what you are looking for.